# find the max values from the multidimensional list of arrays in python

Tags: python-2.7

I have below unsorted multi dimensional array and I have to sorted it based on index no 2 and then find out max index 0 value

```
[[[1, 2], 6, -4], [[1, 4], 10, 0], [[1, 5], 10, 0], [[3, 2], 9, -1], [[3, 4], 15, 5], [[3, 5], 15, 5]]
```

so as per my question, it should print
[3, 4] and [3,5] as they are highest

This is what I did so far, but it's only printing one value not the both values.

```
new_list = sorted(arr, key=lambda x: x[2])
print(max(new_list, key=lambda x: x[2]))
```

this gives me only [[3, 4], 15, 5] not [[3, 5], 15, 5]]
so, how can I say print all of the max values only?

Answer (score 0):

There's two possible ways to get top 2 list items.

First one is to simply get the last two items as the list is already sorted in ascending order.

```
new_list = sorted(arr, key=lambda x: x[2])
print (new_list[-2:])
```

Second way is to get the first max value item, then to get the second max value item from the list, you simple take max of the list that doesn't contain the first max item.

```
new_list = sorted(arr, key=lambda x: x[2])
maxitem = max(new_list, key=lambda x: x[2])
maxitem_Index = new_list.index(maxitem)
secondmaxitem = max(max(new_list[:maxitem_Index]), max(new_list[maxitem_Index+1:]))
```

**EDIT:**

Here's the code that should do what you need:

```
new_list = sorted(arr, key=lambda x: x[2])
print ([item for index, item in enumerate(new_list) if (item[2]==new_list[-1][2])])
```

Basically, in above code we're just iterating through the list items and printing only those which have the same value in second index as the max one.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not going to work because for my sake of example: since there are 2 items but it could be 3 items as well. code should prepare and give the output automatically. whether it's one or two or more. and `max(max(new_list[:maxitem_Index]), max(new_list[maxitem_Index+1:]))` should also max based on key x[2]. e.g. if `new_list = [[[1, 7], 13, -7], [[2, 7], 13, -7], [[1, 3], 24, 4], [[1, 4], 24, 4], [[2, 3], 24, 4], [[2, 4], 24, 4]]`

Comment: It can be easily modified. Just to confirm, can you please tell me the output of this new list, then I'll update the comment with updated code.

Comment: o/o of the new list should be [[1, 3], 24, 4], [[1, 4], 24, 4], [[2, 3], 24, 4], [[2, 4], 24, 4]] as all of them have highest number based on index 2.